# Accidentally changed permissions of /usr/lib to 777

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, ubuntu-20.04

I apologise in advance for poor formatting because my laptop isn't working anymore. I'm on mobile.

I accidentally changed the permissions of /usr/lib to 777 (recursively, with -R). Everything was working fine till I restarted my laptop. Post-restart, my Wifi-adapter couldn't be found, so I have no access to WiFi on my laptop, and sudo stopped working, because the file /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so needs certain permissions but my sweeping change changed it to 777.

I booted up in a live environment using a USB installation medium, and entered the terminal as root. I typed the following in the terminal:

```
# chmod go-w -R /usr/lib
```

But none of the permissions were changed, and for each file contained within I got the message "No space left on device".

I tried to only change the permissions of the top-level directory, as

```
# chmod go-w /usr/lib
```

and also

```
# chmod 744 /usr/lib
```

Both these commands excuted with no error but no stdout either. Upon typing "ls -l" I see that the permissions have not been changed, and /usr/lib still has permissions lrwxrwxrwx.

I mounted /usr (which I know is /dev/sda6 on my laptop) and performed the operations on /mnt/lib but it made no difference. What's going on, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you in a position to back up and reinstall the operating system?

Comment: Most of my important data is backed up and I could reinstall with the same USB live installation medium. Is that the only option? And any idea why chmod isn't working?

Comment: Wholesale permission changes will have changed numerous things and it is unlikely you would catch them all.

Comment: `/usr/lib` from a live environment booted using a USB installation medium is not the `/usr/lib` of your main OS. `/mnt/lib` might be, if you mounted the right filesystem, but we cannot tell. When you say "I accidentally changed the permissions of `/usr/lib` to `777`", do you mean `chmod` with or without `-R`/`--recursive`? Probably with, but please state it explicitly.

Comment: I used the '-R' recursive and the chmod was performed in my main OS. I'm certain that /dev/sda6 is /usr and so /mnt/lib is /usr/lib of main OS. This is because I previously changed the permissions of /usr/bin to 777, and I was able to revert that in a live environment. I had to mount /usr so I used dk in my main OS and found out that /usr is /dev/sda6. Which is why I'm confused why changing the permissions of /usr/bin was reversible but /usr/lib seems to have messed up my system and I can't undo it with chmod in a live env...

Comment: Btw, what does /usr/bin in a live environment correspond to?

Answer (score 1):

A wholesale change to all permissions would change many items.

It is unlikely you could catch them all to back out the changes.

So then, make sure you have a backup and reinstall the operating system.  That is likely the only practical choice at this point.

Comment: I'm afraid John is right. FWIW, [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) or a good full system backup strategy would save you.

Comment: I reinstalled the OS. I couldn't install software because of an 'Incorrect permission on /usr/lib/policykit-1/' error, but this seems to be a common error with a fix and everything is working now. It's funny though, the first time I installed the OS I didn't have this problem...so is it a coincidence or some sort of lingering effect?